# ASP.NET POST request with DateTime as parameter issue

Tags: asp.net, datetime-format

I'm trying to pass from my client-side (angular) a date object to my API. (POST request)

Unforently, The API receives it but the date is absolutely wrong.

**Sending**: Thu Nov 11 2021 10:00:00 GMT+0200

**Reviced**: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

**The controller:**

```
    [HttpPost("{appointment}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SetAppointment(DateTime setAppointment)
    {
        // code
    }
```

**Client-side**

```
setAppointment(date) {
return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + 'barber/appointment', date);}
```

When date - is a DateTime object.

I have tried sending it as a string and then parsing it to a DateTime object and it kind of works but this is not my desired result.

I have tried explicitly parsing the date to a DateTime object on the client-side before sending, but it didn't work as well.

The expected result is to get the date as DateObject straight away in the controller.

Any ideas of why this type of thing happens? I understand that js and c# treat DateTime object in a different way but don't really understand how can I fix it or work around it without sending it as a string.

Thank you !!!

Comment: You need to specify a custom parser... or even easier, just have angular pass in the expected format?

Comment: Can we see a URI example, did you encode it?
Also, typically POST contains a body so why is the date in the URI, unless it's an ID for your appointments?

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari thanks for the quick replay! Could you please explain further what do you mean by angular pass in the expected format? Because I don't really understand why does it happens

Comment: Also, `appointment` != `setAppointment`. They must match. Several issues but that's gonna be your first problem

Comment: Also note that ` 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` is the string representation of the default value of this type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue one: Parameter Naming

The annotation `[HttpPost("{appointment}")]` contains a variable `appointment` which isn't captured by the method `SetAppointment` because none of the parameters have this name. Instead you have a parameter named `setAppointment`. The names will have to match.

### Issue two: URI

No sample URI is provided in the problem, ensure that it is encoded correctly as that is a common pitfall.

### Issue three: Format of Date

Typically a server might have multiple different types of clients using it. Typically the client conforms to the server's date format (use a standard date format though). You can choose to have the server follow the format you are passing from `Angular` so long as it's encoded. In that case you could instead retrieve `appointment` as a `string` and parse it using [a custom date and time format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) that matches what the server will receive.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! you are a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Use `moment` library in Angular in order to send the wanted value in a format that will be automatically cast into DateTime format variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please explain a little further what do you mean?

Comment: I have tried var time = moment(this.time.value); but nothing has changed...